# CoreData : suggestions for model design

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, database-design, model

I'm new with Core Data, and I don't know how to proceed to do what I want.
Actually, I would like to make a model with countries and country codes.

**BUT**: the countries are localized (3 languages for now).
So, here is my model at this time:

Entity: Country
Attributes:

```
 - name_en (String)
 - name_nl (String)
 - name_fr (string)
```

Now, I would like associate country codes for each country.

Example:

```
 - Belgium => BE
 - United States => USA
 - France => FR
```

etc. but it has to work in French and Dutch too.

I don't know how to link this country codes to name_en, name_nl and name_fr.

**Important:** The countries are at the same index in French, English or Dutch:

```
Belgium (en) => index 3
België (nl) => index 3
Belgique (fr) => index 3
```

Hope I've been clear ;)

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise to use the `NSLocale` APIs to cover most of this logic. That would greatly simplify your data structure and instead put the complexity where it belongs - and where Apple can do the heavy lifting for you.

The model would be as simple as this: Entity `Country` with a string attribute `countryCode`, which is the string used by Apple to identify each country. These are strings like

```
en_US
fr_BE
nl_BE
nl_NL
fr_FR
```

If you do not want duplicate entries for the same country with different language region, you could split them into `Country` and `Language` and construct the identifier yourself.

You can generate all the rest with Apple's APIs. E.g., the country code

```
Country *belgium; // assume localeIdentifier "fr_BE" for French
NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:belgium.localeIdentifier];
NSString *belgiumCountryCode = [locale objectForKey:NSLocaleCountryCode];
// --> "BE"
NSString *nameOfBelgiumInFrench = 
    [locale displayNameForKey:NSLocaleCountryCode value:belgiumCountryCode];
// --> "Belgique"
NSLocale *usLocale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
NSString nameOfBelgiumInEnglish = 
    [usLocale displayNameForKey:NSLocaleCountryCode value:belgiumCountryCode];
// --> "Belgium"
```

You can put those cumbersome methods into convenience accessors of your managed object subclasses. Theoretically you could also hard-code them, but I would strongly recommend against it.

One last thing: if you are planning on using Core Data, forget about indexes.

Comment: Nice! Thank you Mundi, I didn't knew this API! :)